# Select a smaller sample of "uniformly" distributed co-ordinates, out of a larger population of co-ordinates

Tags: python, analytics, sample

I have a set of co-ordinates(latitudes and longitudes) of different buildings of a city. The sample size is around 16,000. I plan to use these co-ordinates as the central point of their locality/neighbourhood, and do some analysis on the different neighbourhoods of the city. The "radius/size" for each neighbourhood is still undecided as of now.

However, a lot of these co-ordinates are too close to each other. So, many of them actually represent the same locality/neighbourhood.
As a result, I want to select a smaller sample(say, 3-6k) of co-ordinates that will be more evenly spread out.

Example:- If two of the co-ordinates are representing two neighbouring buildings, I don't want to include both as they pretty much represent the same area. So we must select only one of them.
This way, I was hoping to reduce the population to a smaller size, while at the same time being able to cover most of the city through the remaining co-ordinates.

One way I was imagining the solution is to plot these co-ordinates on a 2D graph(for visualisation). Then, we can select different values of "radius" to see how many co-ordinates would remain. But I do not know how to implement such a "graph".

I am doing this analysis in Python. Is there a way I can obtain such a sample of these co-ordinates that are evenly distributed with minimal overlap?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

It seems like for your use case, you might need clustering instead of sampling to reduce your analysis set.
Given that you'd want to reduce your "houses" data to "neighborhoods" data, I'd suggest exploring geospatial clustering to cluster houses that are closer together and then take your ~3-4K clusters as your data set to begin with.

That being said, if your objective still is to remove houses that are closer together, you can obviously create an N*N matrix of the geospatial distance between each house vs. others and remove pairs that are within (0, X] where X is your threshold.